# Hide links tags that dosen't have text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create this javascript to get all links on  the page and Hide span tag pearent  it if link length  == 0. my problem it hide all span element  with linktext is gerater to than 0
update: I include HTML markup but I have couple of view tile 8 in one page  the a tags ID is lnkBtnTags and it is wrap around span tag

```
<div class="resource" style="position: absolute; left: 240px; top: 0px;">
    <div class="resource-head clearfix">
        <img class="pull-left" src="/ideapark/DesktopModules/ResourcesFilter/img/3.png" alt="icon type" width="36" height="36">
        <p class="resource-title pull-left">
            Learning Strategies
        </p>
        <div class="favorite-resource favorited pull-right">
            <input type="image" name="dnn$ctr687$View$rp_resList$ctl01$imgBtn_bookmark" id="dnn_ctr687_View_rp_resList_imgBtn_bookmark_1" src="/ideaPark/DesktopModules/ResourcesFilter/img/favorite-star-yellow.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="resource-body">
        <input type="hidden" name="dnn$ctr687$View$rp_resList$ctl01$hf_resID" id="dnn_ctr687_View_rp_resList_hf_resID_1" value="92">
        <p class="resource-subtitle"><a href="http://localhost/ideapark/WebsofWonder/SortingMats.aspx">Sorting Mats</a></p>
        <p>
            Sorting Mats are used to assist students in organizing and classifying data and objects.  
        </p>
        <div class="resource-links">
            <p><a id="dnn_ctr687_View_rp_resList_lb_like_1" class="resource-like" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr687$View$rp_resList$ctl01$lb_like','')">Liked</a> <strong>·</strong> <a id="hl_download" class="resource-download hideLinke" href="/ideaPark/DesktopModules/ResourceModule/pdf_resources/">Download</a>  </p>
        </div>
        <div class="resource-tags clearfix">

            <span class="resource-tag pull-left">
                <a id="lnkBtnTags" class="tagsLinks" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr687$View$rp_resList$ctl01$rp_tagsTopics$ctl00$lnkBtnTags','')"></a>
            </span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Script

    $(".tagsLinks").each(function () {
        var linkTxt = $(this).text();
        console.log(linkTxt.length);
        if (linkTxt.length == 0)
        {
            $(".resource-tag").addClass("hideLinke");
        }

    });
```

Comment: Use ===, and also why do you have  $(".resource-tag").addClass("hideLinke");... ??? That's going to apply to all tags.. Not just a specific.

Comment: are spans parent of links? .resource-tag is the class of these spans? Show your markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **this** context along with `closest` if you are targeting the ancestor of the element.

```
$(this).closest(".resource-tag").addClass("hideLinke");
```

**Code**

```
$(".tagsLinks").each(function () {
    // Cache your selector as you are using it multiple times.
    var $this = $(this), 
        linkTxt = $this.text();

    // trim the white spaces
    if (!$.trim(linkTxt).length) { // equivalent to  === 0
        $this.closest(".resource-tag").addClass("hideLinke");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the spans are parent of links, then just use:

```
$(this).parent().addClass("hideLinke");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe improve the JQuery selector ?

$("a.tagsLinks") maybe ?